# MongoDB java regexp not working with map nested in array

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a structure like this:

```
{   
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a9da40e87661b3448b7dfe4"),
    "userList" : [
        {
            "user" : {
                "email" : "Arnold@mail.com",
                "name" : "Arnold"
            },
            "key" : "ArnoldKey"
        }
    ]
}
```

This query in Java works fine:

```
{'userList.user.email' : 'Arnold@mail.com'}
```

And this does not find anything:

```
{'userList.user.email':{ '$regex' : '.*arnold.*' , '$options' : 'i'}}
```

When I remove [] brackets from the structure it works fine, but It's not a solution for me. How should i query to get regex working? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your query like this:

```
 db.getCollection('users').aggregate([{
   $match: {
     'userList.user.name': {
         $regex: `.*arnold.*`,
         $options: 'i'
      }
   }
}]);
```